# I am trying to come up with the "Lebesgue-derivative"

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, lebesgue-integral

so I discovered that the lebesgue integral exists I'm still on chapter 3 of baby Rudin, chapter 2 of Munkres. Is it possible to make something similar that applies to derivatives, if yes, what is it? If no, why, any proof? Basically a derivative for functions which are not continuous. As an example, can you use it on the function f(x) = x! (I know it can be done by turning it into the gamma function but can it be done with this weird derivative I'm talking about which **might not even exist**?)

Comment: There are lots of definitions of derivative, but all have the same underlying ideas. If we thing of differentiation and integration as inverse operations, integration can take discontinuous functions and turn them into differentiable functions - this is the "nasty to nice" direction. Going the other way you might expect "nice to nasty".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a broad question, I'll treat it more as a reference request. You may be interested in the notion of weak derivative (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_derivative), which are used at great length in the study of Sobolev spaces (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space), harmonic analysis, and partial differential equations. These are technical and delicate topics (though the weak derivative page is quite understandable) usually taught at the graduate level.

Essentially, you recall that if $f$ is differentiable, then for any sufficiently smooth test function $\phi$ which is zero outside a big ball, one can integrate by parts $\int f \phi' = -\int f' \phi$. If $f$ is not differentiable, sometimes you can still find a function $g$ such that for any $\phi$ as above one has $\int f \phi' = -\int g \phi$.
In this case $g$ is called a weak derivative of $f$. Such a weak derivative has many nice properties like being unique (up to Lebesgue measure 0).

You can also see other common generalizations of the derivative (of which there are many) on the wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_the_derivative.

Additionally, the study of $f(x) = x!$ is a separate issue. The issue with this one is not that it is not differentiable, it is that $x!$ is usually only defined for natural numbers.
Once you pick the gamma function as a continuation, there is no issue of differentiability. But you could have picked infinitely many other real valued differentiable functions that agree with the factorial on integer values, so it is not like the gamma function is "special" in the sense that it agrees with the factorial and is differentiable. What makes the gamma function special (what uniquely determines it) is that in addition it is logarithmically convex (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#19th%E2%80%9320th_centuries:_characterizing_the_gamma_function).